# bind как получаем аргументы?

Tags: javascript

```js
// bind чтобы привязать контекст 
function bind(func, context){
  return function(){
    return func.apply(context, arguments)
  };
};

// передаем при вызове функции bind
function f(a, b){
  console.log(a + b)
};

// присваиваем в переменную результут функции bind
var q = bind(f, 'context')

// получаем такой результат 


//function(){
//    return f.apply(context, arguments)
//};

// вызываем q с аргументами 2 и 3

q(2, 3);

// вопрос в том что не до конца понял как получили результат в нашем слачае число 5 ?
// Как передается аргументы q(2, 3); в функцию f чтобы получить результат ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объект `arguments` содержит все аргументы, переданные функции (в твоём случае - анонимной функции, которую ты возвращаешь из `bind` и используешь через переменную `q`). А вызов `apply` передаёт их функции `func` (которая является функцией `f`), к которой он применяется.

Comment: я правильно понял что замыкание распространяется и на arguments ?

Comment: @Leks, неправильно. Это аргументы анонимной функции.

Comment: аргументы анонимной функции берет apply и передает  их функции func (которая является функцией f) ?

Comment: @Leks, да, верно. Правда он их не берёт, а принимает и передаёт.

Comment: идем дальше :)) т.к. у анонимной функции не указаны параметры, а q(2, 3); мы указываем аргументы то в анонимной функции они будут хранится в arguments ?

Comment: @Leks, в arguments хранятся все аргументы, независимо от того, указаны они или нет.

Comment: ясно и тогда получается apply будет брать параметры  в анонимной функции из arguments ?

Comment: @Leks, apply будет передавать то, что передали ей, только развернёт и передаст не как есть, а по одному. А ей анонимная функция передала свои аргументы, которые находятся в arguments.

Comment: спасибо (какой-то текст)